# Sql Agent Job: Behavior different than running on command line: starts new process vs. existing process

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent

I'm using sql server agent job (sql server 2019 cu1) to execute a function in a third-party running program. From the command line it is simple:
myProg.exe -myParam
This will always activate the running instance of myProg.exe (if it is not running already) and pass the parameter myParam, executing the desired function. (The behavior is like winword.exe, and unlike notepad.exe: a duplicate instance of myProg.exe will never be created).

But: when executing the same thing as an Sql Server Agent job, I don't get that behavior, whatever I try. Instead, Agent silently runs a NEW and hidden instance of myProg.exe. (I was baffled by this at first, since Agent always reports success, until I opened task manager and saw a zillion copies of MyProg.exe.) Unfortunately a new instance of MyProg.exe does not execute the function (the one triggered by myParam when myProg.exe is called from the command line).

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: I suspect myProg.exe is coded as an GUI form application rather than a console application. Such applications require a message pump thread to handle events that is not available when run as a CMDEXEC job step or xp_cmdshell.

Comment: @Dan Guzman.  Thank you, it is a GUI app, so very likely coded in that way. What I don't get is why this is not an issue when manually typing "myprog.exe -myParam" from the command line, but only when it is automated (via a job step). Do you mean that when a *new* instance of myprog.exe is started, then the message pump is unavailable? Then my question becomes: Why isn't a new instance of myprog also started when manually typing it in the command line -- why is a new instance started only when automated via CMDEXEC or xp_cmdshell? Why the difference in behavior.

Comment: The difference is that when launched from the SQL Agent Windows service, no desktop window is created as there is no interactive user. Without the desktop, OS and User events are not sent to the app to control it. [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/window-messages) describes the Win32 GUI messaging model.

Comment: Thank you for the link, that's helpful.